# Redirecting using PHP (not using header)

Tags: php

Is there a way to redirect using PHP without using `header("Location: http://www.google.com")`? I put that at the top, right after a PHP script (which has no output), but it doesn't work. I use the PHP to check something in the database, and it will redirect depending on the contents.

Comment: In what sense doesn't it work? There must be a problem elsewhere if this is the case - have you checked the HTTP headers that are output to see if the location header is being sent? (Firebug (amongst many others) will let you view the response headers.)

Answer (score 0):

"Right after a PHP script"? Well, it's going to have to be *in* a PHP script to work.

If that's not it, please consider showing your previous code. Remember, don't post a question asking how to implement your solution, but rather the question itself...

Answer (score 0):

Your code should always work as long as the header is called before any echo or print statements that send output to the browser. Another possibility is your webserver sending out additional output or headers that are causing the redirect to not work.

One way to test would be to telnet to your webserver and send GET /myscript.php. Then view the result and see if it is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Per the PHP documentation:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(),
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Without seeing the actual code that the redirect resides in it will be difficult to assist.  Perhaps if you could provide more details then someone may be able to suggest another technology to help but the header method is the only one that I've came across.